# Why am I unable to use sockets in python to connect to a server with an ip address and port number?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, client, python-sockets

I have been searched all over the web and all examples with an ip address and port number connect like how I've done it.

```
 def on_connect(self):
    if self.button1['text'] == "Connect":
        try:
            #host = str(self.ltext1.get())
            #port = int(self.spin1.get())
            host="127.0.0.1"
            port=502
            tcpsocket= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            server_adress = (host,port)
            tcpsocket.connect(server_adress)
            print("sdsd")
            self.button1['text'] = "Disconnect"
        except:
            print("failed")
    else:
        tcpsocket.close()
        self.button1['text'] = "Connect"
```

For me I have a server open at that port and I have successfully connect to it using a C++ client application but when I connect with the same ip address and port number it enter the except meaning the connect failed and my server does not even inform me of any attempt to connect(it does for the C++ client).

Where have I gone wrong in my code or what could possibly be the problem. I also disconnect and close the C++ client application to free up the port for my client.

Comment: I have also tried the bind() command instead of connect() and neither work

Comment: `except` is very broad, it can be any error not related to the server, remove the try/except block and add the resulting error to the question (including traceback), also putting some details about the server may help people, including preferably the reason you think you are using the right port and address.

Comment: If you don't see any connect attempt at the server then it likely does not connect to it. I'm not sure if you aware of it, but 127.0.0.1 is localhost - i.e. client and server must be on the same machine in this case. And as said in another comment: please provide more detailed error information.